# Inserting code from rich text editor in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, rich-text-editor

I use tinymce for form from which I submit some news and it does not insert it into the database
I checked the SQL and it just tries to insert code into the database. It's something like

```
INSERT INTO news (news_title, news, time_added) VALUES (some title, `<p>some text <strong>some strong text</strong></p>`, NOW())
```

and it just does not inserts it into the database
can someone explain me why and what I have to do ?

Comment: use prepared statements. Also provide code of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

you need to html encode the content and then insert

use something like `htmlentities($str)`

Example:

```
encodedStr = htmlentities($html);
```

To decode:

```
$html = html_entity_decode($encodedStr);
```

Comment: yes, so when you print you need to convert raw html back to unescaped form a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);